# SQL Server CTE Implicit Column Datatype issue

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I'm running into a really odd error using a SQL Server Common Table Expression (CTE).

I think it is easiest to explain my issue by giving a code example.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test1 (TestCol varchar(3));

INSERT INTO #Test1 VALUES ('012')
INSERT INTO #Test1 VALUES ('ABC')

--This simple shows the Cast works as expected, and only on rows where the TestCol value is numeric
SELECT TestCol, CAST(TestCol as int) as IntCast 
FROM #Test1 
WHERE ISNUMERIC(TestCol) = 1;

--Here I create a cte using the same SQL as show above.
with cte as (
    SELECT 
       TestCol, CAST(TestCol as int) as IntCast 
    FROM #Test1 
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(TestCol) = 1
)

/*
I have two examples below. The first can be executed to check for the existence of our 'ABC' value.  It doesn't show up, which is expected. 
The Second example, simple checks to see if our IntCast column is greater than 10.  This throws an exception
*/

--SELECT * FROM cte
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE IntCast > 10

DROP TABLE #Test1
```

The exception here is

> *Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'ABC' to data type int*

I'm curious as to where this is occurring?

Comment: My guess would be `CAST(TestCol as int)` ? Try it without the `CAST`?

Comment: No, it shouldn't even be returning 'ABC' in the CTE.

Comment: @Jim - Exactly.  It looks like the order in which things are done are getting changed by the CTE and so the cast is attempted before the filter is applied.  However, done without the cte, it will work.  Strange behavior.

Comment: Subqueries appear to have the same problem: SELECT *
FROM (
 SELECT CAST(TestCol AS INT) AS IntCol
 FROM #Test1
 WHERE ISNUMERIC(TestCol) = 1
 ) AS sub
WHERE IntCol > 10

Comment: [Explained here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors)

Comment: possible duplicate of [error converting varchar to float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085015/error-converting-varchar-to-float)

Comment: looks like the cast is happening before the WHERE, it's getting the whole resultset first and then it filters out the results by using the WHERE;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with cte as (
    SELECT TestCol, Case when ISNUMERIC(TestCol) = 1 then CAST(TestCol as int) else NULL end as IntCast FROM #Test1  
)
```

Comment: This fixes my issue. I appreciate the work around, although I was more interested in the 'why it happened' than the 'how to work around it'. I have accepted your answer all the same.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know, inmy opinion the optimizer seems to take a mysterious path of full evaluation ...